# How to restore GTA 5 from a external hard drive

Tags: steam, pc, grand-theft-auto-v

I bought GTA5 this weekend over steam, then realised that the game is 60GB big and I use a capped line. I asked one of my friends to make a copy of the game so I can restore the game using steam and he copied the folder of where it was installed. How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

I did this several times and I'm sure it works, i did it yesterday when my brother needed help with the same problem. It might not be the cleanest method and wasn't listed in the comment, so i just describe what i did exactly:

**Step 1: DELETE EVERYTHING!**

Yes, you've read it correctly. Right click on the game and press the "Delete local files" button. You need to remove everything at first, otherwise, steam will always continue to download.

**Step 2: Terminate steam**

Don't just go offline. Terminate it via "exit" in the steam menu. Or kill the process. I prefer the last option since i know it's gone for sure then.

**Step 3: Copy the game**

Copy the folder with the downloaded game into the `steamapps\common` folder. Be sure to use the correct name. In case of GTAV, the folder needs to be names `Grand Theft Auto V`. If this isn't the case, steam won't detect it.

**Step 4: Install**

Restart steam, log in and you will see that GTA (or whatever game you're trying to transfer) is not detected yet. Left click on the game and hit the install button. Steam will now detect existing files (took about 10 - 15 minutes on the pc of my brother who did the same btw) and redownload just a small amount of files (around 200 MB).

After you did all that, you're ready to go. It all worked yesterday when i helped my brother with that problem (it would have taken 6 days to download it)

Comment: Well, with your username, I highly doubt it will work. Not a very good choice :P

Comment: @Mathias711 Well, it does work for sure. I did the same often enough when i lived still with my parents, where it took several days to download 10 GB.^^ Sure, it's not the best possibility, but it works and that's all that matters.

Comment: I was just kidding about your username :)